# LibreOffice (Calc) VBA SUM of Cells by index

Tags: openoffice-calc

Is there a possibility, to use SUM() not by Cellnames (A2:A6), but by CellIndex?
Something like =SUM(Sheet.getCellByPosition(0,1):Sheet.getCellByPosition(5,1))

In Excel VBA  its cells(0,1) but how is this in Calc?

Comment: It is unclear whether you are asking about spreadsheet formulas or macros.  My question answers both.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Calc spreadsheet formula.  Documentation: [ADDRESS, INDIRECT, OFFSET, INDEX](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/OOo3_User_Guides/Calc_Guide/Address,_Indirect,_Offset,_Index).

```
=SUM(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(2;1)&":"&ADDRESS(6;1)))
```

The question also mentioned VBA, used for macros in MS Office.  So here is an LO Basic macro, based on [XCellRange](https://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/table/XCellRange.html#getCellRangeByPosition) and https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/88539/from-cell-range-to-array/.

```vb
Function RangeSum(nLeft, nTop, nRight, nBottom)
    oSheet = ThisComponent.CurrentController.ActiveSheet
    oCellRange = oSheet.getCellRangeByPosition(nLeft, nTop, nRight, nBottom)
    svc = createUnoService("com.sun.star.sheet.FunctionAccess")
    RangeSum = svc.callFunction("SUM", Array(oCellRange.Data))
End Function
```